# Yii2 Dropzone already attached & No URL Provided error

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to use dropzone extension for my yii2 project.

I used https://github.com/perminder-klair/yii2-dropzone

My controller :

```
<?php echo \kato\DropZone::widget([
    'options' => [
        'url' => '/dobuyme/frontend/web/index.php?r=boats/create&city_id=2&cat=rowpaddleboats&subcat=paddleboat',
        'maxFilesize' => '2',

    ],
    'clientEvents' => [
        'complete' => "function(file){console.log(file)}",
        'removedfile' => "function(file){alert(file.name + ' is removed')}",
    ],
]);
```

I'm getting error :

> ```
> dropzone.min.js:1 Uncaught Error: No URL provided.
>     at new c (dropzone.min.js:1)
>     at Function.a.discover (dropzone.min.js:1)
>     at a._autoDiscoverFunction (dropzone.min.js:2)
>     at HTMLDocument.f (dropzone.min.js:2)
>
>
> Uncaught Error: Dropzone already attached.
>     at new c (dropzone.min.js:1)
>     at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.php?r=boats/create&city_id=2&cat=rowpaddleboats&subcat=paddleboat:962)
>     at mightThrow (jquery.js:3557)
>     at process (jquery.js:3625)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

### Fault

There is an implementation fault in the extension you are using, the dropzone initialization should not be inside the `jquery` function or `onready` when you are initializing the drop zone without jquery, means if you are using

```
new Dropzone();
```

Then you should better add the script in the end of the page before `</body>` tag without wrapping it inside any of these

- `$(document).ready(function(){})`

or

- `jQuery(function ($) {});`

Which isnt the case with the extension you are using if you look into the view source of the page where you are using dropzone it will show you something like this

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myDropzone", {
        "maxFilesize": "2",
        "url": '/dobuyme/frontend/web/index.php?r=boats/create&city_id=2&cat=rowpaddleboats&subcat=paddleboat',
        "previewsContainer": "#previews",
        "clickable": true,
        "headers": {
            "X-CSRF-Token": "mNq_nlbRIYljqGTXp-bB3nzJelGfikZUzhpLwUapdxbSjMntFZxi5yDgEJjet4WSP60YCc_Gfh6nfAGrdsAbLg=="
        },
        "params": {
            "_csrf": "mNq_nlbRIYljqGTXp-bB3nzJelGfikZUzhpLwUapdxbSjMntFZxi5yDgEJjet4WSP60YCc_Gfh6nfAGrdsAbLg=="
        }
    });
    myDropzone.on('complete', function (file) {
        console.log(file)
    });
    myDropzone.on('removedfile', function (file) {
        alert(file.name + ' is removed')
    });
});
```

and has the same problem as i mentioned above.

### Source of error

The correction is needed in the following line in the source class [`DropZone.php`](https://github.com/perminder-klair/yii2-dropzone/blob/master/DropZone.php#L83)

```
$view->registerJs($js);
```

where Yii2 wrap your the script in the function by default unless you specify in the second parameter of the `registerJs()` function, which in the above case should have been  `\yii\web\View::POS_END`, which make the line.

```
$view->registerJs($js, $view::POS_END);
```

### Solution

What you can do currently to make it work is to extend the class and override the [`registerAssets()`](https://github.com/perminder-klair/yii2-dropzone/blob/master/DropZone.php#L71) function, and change the line so what you will do is.

1. Create a file `DropZone.php` inside the `common/components` folder, if there isnt any folder with the name `/components` inside the `common/` folder on the root of your project then create one, and add the following code inside the file.

   ```
   namespace common\components;

   use yii\helpers\Json;
   use kato\assets\DropZoneAsset;
   use kato\DropZone as KatoDropZone;

   class DropZone extends KatoDropZone
   {
       public function registerAssets()
       {
           $view = $this->getView();
           $autoDiscover = $this->autoDiscover;
           $id = $this->id;
           $dropzoneContainer = $this->dropzoneContainer;
           $options = Json::encode($this->options);

           $js = <<<JS
           Dropzone.autoDiscover = $autoDiscover;
           var $id= new Dropzone("div#$dropzoneContainer",$options);
   JS;

           if (!empty($this->clientEvents)) {
               foreach ($this->clientEvents as $event => $handler) {
                   $js .= "$this->id.on('$event', $handler);";
               }
           }

           $view->registerJs($js, $view::POS_END);
           DropZoneAsset::register($view);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Now use your custom class in the view and change the namespace from `\kato\DropZone::widget()` to `\common\Dropzone::widget()` and thats it. it should work smooth, your view code should look like below.

   ```
   echo \common\DropZone::widget([
       'options' => [
           'url' => '/dobuyme/frontend/web/index.php?r=boats/create&city_id=2&cat=rowpaddleboats&subcat=paddleboat',
           'maxFilesize' => '2',

       ],
       'clientEvents' => [
           'complete' => "function(file){console.log(file)}",
           'removedfile' => "function(file){alert(file.name + ' is removed')}",
       ],
   ]);
   ```