# am using dropzone in yii2 but i have error

Tags: yii2, dropzone

in form

```
<?php 
          try {
            echo \kato\DropZone::widget([
                'options' => [
                    'maxFilesize' => '10',
                    'url'         => yii::$app->urlManager->baseUrl.'/items/items/uploads' ,
                ],
                'clientEvents' => [
                    'complete' => "function(file){console.log(file)}",
                    'removedfile' => "function(file){alert(file.name + ' is removed')}"
                ],
            ]);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
        }
        ?>
```

error display in console

> Uncaught Error: No URL provided.
> at new c (dropzone.min.js:1)
> at Function.a.discover (dropzone.min.js:1)
> at a._autoDiscoverFunction (dropzone.min.js:2)
> at HTMLDocument.f (dropzone.min.js:2)

> Uncaught Error: Dropzone already attached.
> at new c (dropzone.min.js:1)
> at HTMLDocument. (create:558)
> at mightThrow (jquery.js:3762)
> at process (jquery.js:3830)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yii2 Dropzone already attached & No URL Provided error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59398236/yii2-dropzone-already-attached-no-url-provided-error)

Comment: There is an almost identical question with a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59400647/2557030).